# Изменить изображения профиля на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

У каждого юзера есть возможность загрузить фото профиля на сайт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу чтобы при клике на изображение, появлялась форма для выбора файла, после чего файл отправлялся на сервер. Серверную часть написать не проблема, но вот сделать так чтобы при клике на изображение появлялась форма, та еще проблема. Имею вот такой код

```
 <div class="profile">

            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="file"  class="custom-file-input" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail">
                <img src="img/profile.jpg" class="wd-150 rounded-circle center-block profile-photo" alt="">


                <p class="op-5 tx-30 white-text">otricvla</p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Проблема тут в том, что форма выбора файла не на самом изображении.

Comment: ```var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'file';
input.click();```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215771/how-to-open-select-file-dialog-via-js

Comment: Модальная форма? Асинхрон через Ajax  может нужно?

Comment: Т.е. Вы хотите, чтоб при клике форма появлялась ВМЕСТО изображения? Так сделайте Ваш `<input >` невидимым, при клике по `<img>` скрывайте его и `<p>`, а `<input>` показывайте. При успешной загрузке нового изображения - видимость меняйте обратно

Comment: Получилось ли у вас реализовать данную задачу? если да, могли бы вы поделиться решением?